# Reportlab balanced cols control split of flowables

Tags: python, python-3.x, reportlab

I am using `BalancedColumns` to generate multiple column layout.
I am not sure, how to resolve an issue of the split happening of the `Flowables` across the column frames.

I have a heading and it's content. I don't want BalancedColumns to split the flowables in such a way that heading is part of one column and its content is part of another.

The content of the paragraph can split.

The basic python code:

```py
from reportlab.platypus.flowables import BalancedColumns, CondPageBreak
from reportlab.platypus import BaseDocTemplate, Paragraph, Spacer, Frame, PageTemplate, PageBreak
from reportlab.lib.units import mm
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4, LETTER
import os
from reportlab.lib.colors import HexColor

framewidth = A4[0] - 10*mm
frameheight = A4[1] - 20*mm
portrait_frame = Frame(5*mm, 10*mm, framewidth, frameheight, 
                                    leftPadding=0, 
                                    bottomPadding=0, 
                                    rightPadding=0, 
                                    topPadding=0, 
                                    id=0, 
                                    showBoundary=False )
pTemplate = PageTemplate(id=0,frames=[portrait_frame])
templates = [pTemplate]


pdfPath = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'balancedColTest.pdf'))

doc = BaseDocTemplate(pdfPath, pagesize=A4, rightMargin=2*mm, leftMargin=2*mm,topMargin=5*mm,bottomMargin=5*mm,showBoundary=0) 
doc.addPageTemplates(templates)

# generate stories for balanced columns
story = []
minPadding = 2
for i in range(3):
    fs = []
    numOfFlowables = random.choice([2, 5, 6, 1, 3])
    padding = minPadding + 5*i

    for ii in range(numOfFlowables):
        text = '<b> <font color="#77D179"> Heading </font></b> <br/>'
        heading = Paragraph(text)
        heading.keepWithNext = True
        fs.append(heading)
        fs.append(Paragraph("This is another text in new Para flowable."))
   

    # numCols = 2 if i%2 == 0 else 3
    numCols = 2
    bCols = BalancedColumns(fs, nCols=numCols, spaceAfter=5*mm, vLinesStrokeColor=HexColor('#77D179'), vLinesStrokeWidth=0.5)
    story.append(bCols)

doc.build(story)
```

[image: Issue demo]

Even if I try to use `keepWithNext=True` the flowables are not part of same frame.

If I use `KeepTogether`, the BalanceColumns takes the entire space of the page.

```py
        heading = Paragraph(text)
        content = Paragraph("This is another text in the paragraph")
        f= KeepTogether([heading, content])
        fs.append(f)
```

[image: Issue with KeepTogether]

Can anyone suggest a solution so that the heading and its underlying paragraph can remain in the same frame?